# Hundreds of threads are getting created on JBOSS server

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, threadpool

We have springboot application which have postgres database connection. After deploying the service on jboss, hundreds of threads getting created due to which service breaks in between.

Can anyone suggest what could be the possibilities?

Comment: Many possibilities.  What information have you gathered on the runaways threads?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.